# Java List on disk

Tags: java, list, serialization

Assume I have a very long list of (serializable) elements and I get problems with my heap space. Is there a standard way to create an object of type List which holds its contents on hard disk (and does some caching for providing iterators)?

Comment: I guess no. You need to write them to file/disk and read them later.

Comment: What about increasing heap space or using a database?

Comment: The main program is constructed to work with lists. In exceptional cases, these lists are large. I am looking for a simple way to stay with the List paradigm without running out of heap space. The reduced speed of the process is not so important.

Comment: You could probably write a list that memory maps a file and reads its contents from that file but the first questions I'd ask would be: Why is the file that big? Why does it need to represent a single list? Why don't you use a more appropriate data source for bigger amounts of data, e.g. a database (might be an embedded RDBMS like Derby or H2)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773864/java-collection-which-pages-to-disk-when-it-gets-full, http://www.mapdb.org/ etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help you: [Memory mapped collections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800613/memory-mapped-collections-in-java)

Especially the library linked in the accepted answer looks promising. From the readme:

> It uses almost no heap, trivial GC impact, can be much larger than your physical memory size (only limited by the size of your disk) and can be shared between processes with better than 1/10th latency of using Sockets over loopback.

And from the answer:

> It really design for List & Queue ...